# Android market- cannot find application on specific devices without bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-play, android-permissions

I have an application that cannot be seen on specific devices without bluetooth.
The problem is that in my manifest file I have a bluetooth permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false"></uses-permission>
```

Programmatically I excluded bluetooth option for that devices, but I cannot find my app on market on that devices.

So, 3 questions:

1. Is there a tool that can show me the list of
   devices available on market? Like
   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1286017
   but only not on market
2. Can I somehow add this permision only for
   devices with bluetooth?
3. All other solution that can help me to
   find my app on market (but to keep permission for devices with
   bluetooth).

Comment: When you once upload it on market, it'll show you a link in Publishing area. That link will show you all the compatible android devices for your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you also have

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" />
```

in the manifest. You can try to add `android:required="false"` to that.

Comment: I do not have it, only bluetooth_admin and bluetooth

Comment: The above clause declares that the device should have bluetooth, with required false you say it is optional.